# Можно ли выполнять таски Android приложения в фоновом режиме?

Tags: android, task

Тема вопроса немного не соответствует действительности. Так и не смог придумать что-то толковое. В общем, создаём мы с другом приложение на Android, которое должно периодически делать API запросы к датчикам, получать с них информацию и сохранять их в памяти телефона. Можно ли это реализовать без необходимости держать приложение открытым, и если можно то какие разрешения нужны? Я слышал о фоновом воспроизведении приложений, но оно ли это?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: AlarmManager....

Comment: Спасибо большое! Alarm manager тут не совсем подходит, work manager - как раз то что нужно!